# Conversion from Tensorflow to Onnx

Tags: tensorflow, onnx

I want to transform this TF model: [ICNET_0.5](https://github.com/oandrienko/fast-semantic-segmentation/blob/master/docs/model_zoo.md) to onnx and I followed this example: [ConvertingSSDMobilenetToONNX](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/blob/master/tutorials/ConvertingSSDMobilenetToONNX.ipynb)

I understood if I just want to inference I should use the frozen graph (in my case: `frozen_inference_graph.pb`) so I changed the name to `savel_model.pb`  (it seems that tf2onnx does not recognize other name) and run the following with this error:

```
C:\Users\esarojp\Desktop\newmodel\0818_icnet_0.5_1025_resnet_v1.tar> python -m tf2onnx.convert --opset 10 --fold_const --saved-model .\0818_icnet_0.5_1025_resnet_v1\saved_model\ --output MODEL.onnx

 - WARNING - From C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf2onnx\verbose_logging.py:72: The name tf.logging.set_verbosity is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf2onnx\convert.py", line 161, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf2onnx\convert.py", line 123, in main
    args.saved_model, args.inputs, args.outputs, args.signature_def)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf2onnx\loader.py", line 103, in from_saved_model
    meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], model_path)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 269, in load
    return loader.load(sess, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 422, in load
    **saver_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 349, in load_graph
    meta_graph_def = self.get_meta_graph_def_from_tags(tags)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 327, in get_meta_graph_def_from_tags
    "\navailable_tags: " + str(available_tags))
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
available_tags: [set()]
```

and when I run:

```
C:\Users\esarojp\Desktop\newmodel\0818_icnet_0.5_1025_resnet_v1.tar> saved_model_cli show --dir .\0818_icnet_0.5_1025_resnet_v1\saved_model\ --tag_set serve  --signature_def serving_default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\saved_model_cli-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\saved_model_cli.py", line 909, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\saved_model_cli.py", line 621, in show
    _show_inputs_outputs(args.dir, args.tag_set, args.signature_def)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\saved_model_cli.py", line 133, in _show_inputs_outputs
    tag_set)
  File "C:\Users\esarojp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\saved_model_utils.py", line 120, in get_meta_graph_def
    ' could not be found in SavedModel')
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tag-set serve could not be found in SavedModel
```

I think that something is pointing to `frozen_inference_graph.pb` on the other files but it does not exist anymore (although it says that all the weights are inside the graph).

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did it wrong, I tried to convert the model from a SavedModel using a Frozen graph, to convert a Frozen graph it is needed to add graphdef flag and to specify inputs and outputs.

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --graphdef .\0818_icnet_0.5_1025_resnet_v1\frozen_inference_graph.pb --output frozen.onnx --fold_const --opset 10   --inputs inputs:0 --outputs predictions:0
```